# I want to load a different webpage before HTML loads - AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, rest

I want to load a different webpage (Like:google.com) based on the response of a REST API in an AngularJS app before any HTML loads for the default view of the AngularJS app.

I have already tried making a REST service call in a factory and using the response in the .run function of my app, but before the page redirects i am able to see the Angular App's HTML view.

```
var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);
app.run(function(myService,$window) {
myService.someFunc().then(function(data){
      $window.location.href = 'http://www.google.com';
  });
});

app.factory('myService',function($http,$window,$q){
var self = this;
this.someFunc = function someFunc (){
        var deffered = $q.defer();
        $http.get('someAPI').success(function(data){
            deffered.resolve(data)
        }).error(function(error){
            deffered.reject(error)
        });
        return deffered.promise;
    }
return self;
}):
```

Comment: You could maybe use ngCloak to hide the HTML until everything has loaded and been processed?

Comment: either use a resolve in router or make request outside angular and manually bootstrap app in callback. A router resolve delays loading controller and template. Agree with answer below though that it's best to show something

Comment: @chris22smith: If i am correct ng-cloak is used to used to prevent the Angular html template from being briefly displayed by the browser in its raw (uncompiled) form while your application is loading. But i do not want anything to load before i have the response from the REST API. Thanks for your suggeston

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is a problem you shouldn't be solving the hard way. It seems hard from an angular perspective, but much more importantly it's a bad experience for the user.

I would suggest to use a full page overlay as the page loads, write something nice to the user, maybe an ajax loading icon etc. so the user knows he's waiting for a reason and the page isn't just slow. Then when your ajax call returns just fade it away and everyone's happy :)

Comment: Thanks for you suggestion. But i want to make a decision  (based on response from REST API) before the page load has started to load one of the 2 different pages which i have created (1 with Angular and other with JavaScript) i have achieved the desired result with Javascript but now i want to do similar thing in AngularJS.